# Can't call to item menu after update xamrain 15.7.1

Tags: android, xamarin, menu

Hi this first question.

I have a problem connecting to the menu items after the update xamarin 15.7.1, and the problem was not present before the update:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please avoid showing code in image links. Write your code directly in the post, so it can be more readable.

Comment: Please delete the bin and obj folder, and restart your VS.